# waiting on a locked NSLock until tryLock succeeds

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, nslock

I have a class with 2 methods, the first one makes an animation for a second and the second performs some task.

This class is being called from a second class to perform those two operations consecutively but I want to enforce a lock so that the second operation runs only when the first one finished.

My Question is, what is the best way to do that.

here is my code:

```
@implementation Server


- (id)init{

    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        syncLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)operationA {
    NSLog(@"op A started");

    [syncLock lock];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:view];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"opA" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5f];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)animationFinished {
    [syncLock unlock];
    NSLog(@"Op A finished");

}

- (void)operationB {
    if ( ![syncLock tryLock]) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(operationB) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"op B started");

    NSLog(@"perform some task here");
    [syncLock unlock];
    NSLog(@"op B finished");
}
@end
```

And the code that calls it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    Server *server = [[Server alloc] init];
    [server operationA];
    [server operationB];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Change operation A to be a BOOL method and return YES once completed and in your AppController

```
if([server operationA]) // operation A returns YES when completed so run operationB
    [server operationB];
```

**Option 2** *added as per JeremyP's comment*

in your delegate method (animationFinished:) for OperationA add `[self operationB];` to run `operationB:` at the end of your animation cycle.

Comment: You could also make the call to [self operationB] from within your delegate method (animationFinished:).

Comment: I could do both of those thing, but what interest me is that the AppDelegate or the calling class call these separately from different points and OpA & OpB are loosely coupled. Not every time A gets called B gets Called.

Comment: Your comment should go in the answer.  I think it is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @JeremyP thanks for your suggestion. but what if its not an animation for example and there is not call back function like animationFinished. I am looking for a more basic solution that will work with any NSLock situation. so far the timer solution seems the most reasonable one but I am looking for a solution that works in any case using the NSLock. I appreciate your help though